# How can I solve the problem of changing the background color of the appBar when I scroll?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a problem that scrolling through the page changes the background color of the appBar. How can I solve it? and what is the problem? GIF description link => https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRQNP.gif

```
class SearchBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchBarWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchBarWidget> createState() => _SearchBarWidgetState();
}

class _SearchBarWidgetState extends State<SearchBarWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      toolbarHeight: 70,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
      .
      .
      .
```

```
class CommunityScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CommunityScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CommunityScreen> createState() => _CommunityScreenState();
}

class _CommunityScreenState extends State<CommunityScreen> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
        child: SearchBarWidget(),
      ),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (scrollNotification) => true,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Material 3, `elevation` of the app bar is indicated by a change in color (as opposed to the drop shadow conventionally used in Material 2).

See here for more info: https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/overview

To prevent this behaviour, you can tell the app bar that it shouldn't apply elevation when scrolled under:

```dart
AppBar(
  ...,
  scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
),
```

But you might also consider embracing the conventions proposed by the material specification, by removing the divider and using the color to separate the app bar from the page content.